# Error on opening MainStoryBoard.storyboard in Xamarin studio 5.7.2 (build 7)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Am getting the below error on opening the empty(default template) single view application with the system configuration Xcode 6.3.2 (7718),Xamarin.iOS Version: 8.6.2.26 (Enterprise Edition),Mac OS X 10.10.3. Is there any solution?

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f1] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1251 
  at Mono.Unix.UnixClient.Connect (Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint remoteEndPoint) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixClient.cs:170 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Unix.UnixClient:Connect (Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint)
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.SendRequestImpl (System.Action`1 send) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.7-branch/dcf3f486/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:115 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (System.Action`1 send, System.Action`1 recv, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.7-branch/dcf3f486/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:278 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f1] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1251 
  at Mono.Unix.UnixClient.Connect (Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint remoteEndPoint) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixClient.cs:170 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Unix.UnixClient:Connect (Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint)
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.SendRequestImpl (System.Action`1 send) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.7-branch/dcf3f486/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:115 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (System.Action`1 send, System.Action`1 recv, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-5.7-branch/dcf3f486/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:278 <---

Comment: Enterprise edition? Why not Xamarin support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Xamarin support team suggestion I have downloaded the latest Xamarin Studio 5.9.3(build 1) and everything is working fine.